# Why am I getting the Recursion statement?

Tags: recursion, pygame

All I've done was added more sprites to the list called ALL(for sprites) and the corresponding functions. I expected everything to be fine but ironicly it isn't when running the whole code I get an error about A recursive error something that is basically repeating itself multiple times or something like that anyway here is the code.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
phrase2 = "How are you?"
phrase3 = "What's your name?"
phrase4 = "Fine, thank you."
phrase5 = "My name is ______"
phrase6 = "Its Hot!"
phrase7 = "Its Cold!"
phrase8 = "What time is it?"
phrase9 = "The time is ______"
phrase10 = "Half past 7"


nub1 = "1)"
nub2 = "2)"
nub3 = "3)"
nub4 = "4)"
nub5 = "5)"
nub6 = "6)"
nub7 = "7)"
nub8 = "8)"
nub9 = "9)"
nub10 = "10)"


 
startunclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Unclicked.png")
startclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Clicked.png")

optionunclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Option.png")
optionclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/OptionCLICKED.png")
optoinunclikf = pg.transform.scale(optionunclik, (228, 76))
optoinclikf = pg.transform.scale(optionclik, (228, 76))
option1 = optoinunclikf
option2 = optoinclikf

UParrow = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/UPARROW.png")
UParrowclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/UPARROWClicked.png")
DOWNarrow = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/DOWNARROW.png")
DOWNarrowclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/DOWNARROWClicked.png")

UPBOXy = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/UPbox.png")

drop = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Setingdropbox.jpg")

audiopt = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Audio.png")
audioptClic = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/AudioCLICKED.png")

xit = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/EXIT.jpg")
xitclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/EXITCLICKED.jpg")

go = 0

A = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/A.png")
B = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/B.png")
C = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/C.png")
D = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/D.png")
E = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/E.png")
F = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/F.png")
G = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/G.png")
H = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/H.png")
I = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/I.png")
J = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/J.png")
K = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/K.png")
L = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/L.png")
M = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/M.png")
N = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/N.png")
O = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/O.png")
P = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/P.png")
Q = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Q.png")
R = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/R.png")
S = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/S.png")
T = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/T.png")
U = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/U.png")
V = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/V.png")
W = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/W.png")
Xl = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/X.png")
Y = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Y.png")
Z = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Z.png")

Aclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/A.hoverdpng.png")
Bclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/B.hoverd.png")
Cclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/C.hoverdpng.png")
Dclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/D.hoverd.png")
Eclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/E.hoverd.png")
Fclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/F.hoverdpng.png")
Gclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/G.hoverd.png")
Hclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/H.hoverd.png")
Iclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/I.hoverd.png")
Jclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/J.hoverd.png")
Kclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/K.hoverd.png")
Lclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/L.hoverd.png")
Mclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/M.hoverd.png")
Nclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/N.hoverd.png")
Oclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/O.hoverd.png")
Pclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/P.hoverd.png")
Qclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Q.hoverd.png")
Rclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/R.hoverd.png")
Sclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/S.hoverd.png")
Tclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/T.hoverd.png")
Uclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/U.hoverd.png")
Vclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/V.hoverd.png")
Wclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/W.hoverd.png")
Xclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/X.hoverd.png")
Yclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Y.hoverd.png")
Zclik = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/Z.hoverd.png")


cliknum1 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/1.hoverd.png")
cliknum2 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/2.hoverd.png")
cliknum3 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/3.hoverd.png")
cliknum4 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/4.hovered.png")
cliknum5 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/5.hovered.png")
cliknum6 = pg.image.load("Platformer Objectiles/6.hovered.png")



user_text = ""
disable = 0

white = 255, 255, 255
lgrey = 192, 192, 192
grey = 128, 128, 128
dgrey = 64, 64, 64
black = 0, 0, 0
dbrown = 128, 64, 0
brown = 192, 128, 0
lbrown = 225, 156, 0
red = 255, 0, 0
orange = 255, 128, 0
yellow = 255, 223, 0
lgreen = 128, 255, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
dgreen = 0, 128, 0
ddgreen = 0, 64, 0
turcoise = 0, 192, 128
llblue = 0, 192, 255
lblue = 0, 128, 255
blue = 0, 0, 255
dblue = 0, 0, 128
ddblue = 0, 0, 64
blurple = 128, 0, 192
purple = 192, 0, 192
pirple = 167, 0, 167
rpink = 255, 0, 128
pink = 255, 0, 255


win = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 610))
pg.display.set_caption("SPANISH")
win.fill(orange)

class Question(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render("What is the Spanish translation of:", True, ddgreen)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


quiz = Question()
quiz.rect.x = 35
quiz.rect.y = 110


class Phrase(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase2, True, dgrey)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras = Phrase()
phras.rect.x = 35
phras.rect.y = 150


class Phrase2(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase3, False, dgrey)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras2 = Phrase2()
phras2.rect.x = 35
phras2.rect.y = 150


class Phrase3(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase4, False, dgrey)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras3 = Phrase3()
phras3.rect.x = 35
phras3.rect.y = 150


class Phrase4(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase5, False, dgrey)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras4 = Phrase4()
phras4.rect.x = 35
phras4.rect.y = 150


class Phrase5(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase6, False, purple)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras5 = Phrase5()
phras5.rect.x = 35
phras5.rect.y = 150


class Phrase6(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase7, False, black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras6 = Phrase6()
phras6.rect.x = 35
phras6.rect.y = 150


class Phrase7(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase8, False, black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras7 = Phrase7()
phras7.rect.x = 35
phras7.rect.y = 150


class Phrase8(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase9, False, pink)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras8 = Phrase8()
phras8.rect.x = 35
phras8.rect.y = 150


class Phrase9(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase10, False, dgrey)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras9 = Phrase9()
phras9.rect.x = 35
phras9.rect.y = 150

ALL = pg.sprite.Group()


def redraw():

    ALL.draw(win)
    pg.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    ALL.add(play)
    print(len(user_text), "disab =", disable)
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    pg.time.delay(95)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        key = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pg.K_BACKSPACE]:
            user_text = user_text[:-1]
        else:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                user_text += event.unicode

        if key[pg.K_RETURN] and len(user_text) <= 11 and disable == 2:
            disable = 5
            user_text = ""
        if disable == 5:
            win.fill(pink)
            play.image.fill(pink)
            bg.image.fill(llblue)
            ALL.remove(phras)
            ALL.add(phras2)
            ALL.remove(umbr1)
            ALL.add(umbr2)

        if disable == 5 and key[pg.K_RETURN] and len(user_text) >= 14:
            user_text = ""
            disable = 6
        if disable == 6:
            win.fill(white)
            play.image.fill(white)
            bg.image.fill(black)
            ALL.remove(phras2)
            ALL.add(phras3)
            ALL.remove(umbr2)
            ALL.add(umbr3)

        if disable == 6 and key[pg.K_RETURN] and len(user_text) >= 11:
            user_text = ""
            disable = 7
        if disable == 7:
            win.fill(lgrey)
            play.image.fill(lgrey)
            bg.image.fill(grey)
            ALL.remove(phras3)
            ALL.add(phras4)
            ALL.remove(umbr3)
            ALL.add(umbr4)

        if disable == 7 and key[pg.K_RETURN] and len(user_text) >= 11:
            user_text = ""
            disable = 8
        if disable == 8:
            win.fill(dgrey)
            play.image.fill(dgrey)
            bg.image.fill(white)
            ALL.remove(phras4)
            ALL.add(phras5)
            ALL.remove(umbr4)
            ALL.add(umbr5)

        if disable == 8 and key[pg.K_RETURN] and len(user_text) >= 9:
            user_text = ""
            disable = 9
        if disable == 9:
            win.fill(dblue)
            play.image.fill(dblue)
            bg.image.fill(llblue)
            ALL.remove(phras5)
            ALL.add(phrase6)  <<<---------------->>> This is the cause of the error
            ALL.remove(umbr5)
            ALL.add(umbr6)



        user_txt.update(user_text)

        user_txt.rect.x = 70
        user_txt.rect.y = 270

        if play.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            play.image = startclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                disable = 1
                play.image.fill(llblue)
                ALL.add(bg_quiz, quiz_txt)
        else:
            play.image = startunclik

        if disable == 1:
            play.image.fill(llblue)
            win.fill(llblue)
            ALL.remove(play)

            if disable == 0:
                play.image = startunclik

            if len(user_text) == 15:
                user_text = user_text[:-1]

        if bg_quiz.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            bg_quiz.image.fill(yellow)
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bg_quiz.image.fill(llblue)
            disable = 2
            ALL.remove(bg_quiz, quiz_txt)
        else:
            bg_quiz.image.fill(green)

        if disable == 2:
            win.fill(green)
            play.image.fill(green)
            ALL.add(bg, user_txt, arrowup, quiz, phras, umbr1)
            play.image.fill(green)

        if boxup.rect.y <= 256:
            go = 1

        if arrowup.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            arrowup.image = DOWNarrow
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and go == 1:
                go = 2
        if go == 2 and not(arrowup.rect.collidepoint(pos)):
            arrowup.image = DOWNarrowclik

        if boxup.rect.y >= 606:
            go = 0

        if arrowup.rect.collidepoint(pos) and disable == 2:
            arrowup.image = UParrow
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and disable == 2 and go == 0:
                disable = 3
                ALL.add(boxup, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i,
                        j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
                        u, v, w, xa, yl, zl)
        if go == 0 and disable == 2 and not(arrowup.rect.collidepoint(pos)):
            arrowup.image = UParrowclik

        if go == 1:
            win.fill(green)
            arrowup.rect.y += 20
            boxup.rect.y += 20
            a.rect.y += 20
            b.rect.y += 20
            c.rect.y += 20
            d.rect.y += 20
            e.rect.y += 20
            f.rect.y += 20
            g.rect.y += 20
            h.rect.y += 20
            i.rect.y += 20
            j.rect.y += 20
            k.rect.y += 20
            l.rect.y += 20
            m.rect.y += 20
            n.rect.y += 20
            o.rect.y += 20
            p.rect.y += 20
            q.rect.y += 20
            r.rect.y += 20
            s.rect.y += 20
            t.rect.y += 20
            u.rect.y += 20
            v.rect.y += 20
            w.rect.y += 20
            xa.rect.y += 20
            yl.rect.y += 20
            zl.rect.y += 20


        if a.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            a.image = Aclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "A"
        else:
            a.image = A

        if b.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            b.image = Bclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "B"
        else:
            b.image = B

        if c.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            c.image = Cclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "C"
        else:
            c.image = C

        if d.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            d.image = Dclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "D"
        else:
            d.image = D

        if e.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            e.image = Eclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "E"
        else:
            e.image = E

        if f.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            f.image = Fclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "F"
        else:
            f.image = F

        if g.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            g.image = Gclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "G"
        else:
            g.image = G

        if h.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            h.image = Hclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "H"
        else:
            h.image = H

        if i.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            i.image = Iclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "I"
        else:
            i.image = I

        if j.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            j.image = Jclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            user_text += "J"
        else:
            j.image = J

        if k.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            k.image = Kclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "K"
        else:
            k.image = K

        if l.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            l.image = Lclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "L"
        else:
            l.image = L

        if m.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            m.image = Mclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "M"
        else:
            m.image = M

        if n.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            n.image = Nclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "N"
        else:
            n.image = N

        if o.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            o.image = Oclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "O"
        else:
            o.image = O

        if p.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            p.image = Pclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "P"
        else:
            p.image = P

        if q.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            q.image = Qclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "Q"
        else:
            q.image = Q

        if r.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            r.image = Rclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "R"
        else:
            r.image = R

        if s.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            s.image = Sclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "S"
        else:
            s.image = S

        if t.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            t.image = Tclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "T"
        else:
            t.image = T

        if u.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            u.image = Uclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "U"
        else:
            u.image = U

        if v.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            v.image = Vclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "V"
        else:
            v.image = V

        if w.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            w.image = Wclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "W"
        else:
            w.image = W

        if xa.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            xa.image = Xclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "X"
        else:
            xa.image = Xl

        if yl.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            yl.image = Yclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "Y"
        else:
            yl.image = Y
        if zl.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            zl.image = Zclik
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                user_text += "Z"
        else:
           zl.image = Z
    if go == 2 and boxup.rect.y > 256:
        win.fill(green)

        play.rect.x = 1000
        play.rect.y = 0
        arrowup.rect.y -= 10
        boxup.rect.y -= 10
        a.rect.y -= 10
        b.rect.y -= 10
        c.rect.y -= 10
        d.rect.y -= 10
        e.rect.y -= 10
        f.rect.y -= 10
        g.rect.y -= 10
        h.rect.y -= 10
        i.rect.y -= 10
        j.rect.y -= 10
        k.rect.y -= 10
        l.rect.y -= 10
        m.rect.y -= 10
        n.rect.y -= 10
        o.rect.y -= 10
        p.rect.y -= 10
        q.rect.y -= 10
        r.rect.y -= 10
        s.rect.y -= 10
        t.rect.y -= 10
        u.rect.y -= 10
        v.rect.y -= 10
        w.rect.y -= 10
        xa.rect.y -= 10
        yl.rect.y -= 10
        zl.rect.y -= 10


    pg.display.flip()
    redraw()
pg.quit()
```

Comment: Here is the Error code                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                    if isinstance(sprite, Sprite):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You can make your code a lot shorter. Classes are made to have multiple objects. You can save your phrases in a list and loop over it and create a sprite from one single class. The same applies to your mouse position collision. It would make your code way more readable.

Comment: Jerry what does it look like to loop over phrases in a list? I only go by examples it is understandable what you said but my brain does not work like that I need examples to understand clearly, but thank you.

Comment: I would make a list of phrases: `phrases = ("How are you", "What's your name", )` and loop over it `phraseSprites = [PhraseSprite(phrase) for phrase in phrases]`. In that example you would have one single class `PhraseSprite` which revieces the phrase string  and uses it to render the text. `class PhraseSprite:  def __init__(self, phrase):  ...  self.image = font.render(phrase, True, dgrey)` Of course you can have a second parameter called `antialias`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phrase6 = "Its Hot!" # phase6 is a string variable 

class Phrase5(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(phrase6, False, purple)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


phras5 = Phrase5()
phras5.rect.x = 35
phras5.rect.y = 150

   if disable == 9:
        win.fill(dblue)
        play.image.fill(dblue)
        bg.image.fill(llblue)
        ALL.remove(phras5)
        ALL.add(phrase6)  <<<---------------->>> #The cause of the error is 
        becuase i wanted to add the Sprite phras6=Phrase6() But instead chose 
        the string variable phrase6="It's Hot!"
        ALL.remove(umbr5)
        ALL.add(umbr6)
```

I figured out the reason why I got the error.........It's because I chose the string (phrase6) Instead of phras6 (The class).